# Parse a date and retrieve specificity in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm building a system that let's users enter a complete or incomplete date, and then find a list of dates matching that query in the database.

The `dateutil` package is fine for parsing the string itself, but I also need the specificity, in other words:

- "20/3/2018" parses, and is specific to the day
- "June" parses (to 2018-06-20 if today is 2018-08-20, as it uses today's date), but is specific to the *month*, i.e. I would expect any row in the database in June to match
- 2018 parses, and is specific to the year

Once I know the specificity, I can easily work out upper and lower ranges. How do I parse a string from a date and also retrieve the specificity at the same time?

*Edit: Example input output pairs*
The current behaviour of dateutil is to fill missing data with the current data. So if today is the 25th of August, 2018, I would expect:

- **input -> output**
- "2019-07-26" -> `(datetime(2019, 7, 26), "daily")`
- "2019-07" -> `(datetime(2019, 7, 25), "monthly")`
- "2019" -> `(datetime(2019, 8, 25), "yearly")`
- "June" -> `(datetime(2018, 6, 25), "monthly")`

The exact format of the output doesn't matter, as long as it's clear what the specificity is. I would also want to be able to parse all input date formats that dateutil parses, and I don't care specifically if the datetime is there (because dateutil gives me that).

Comment: Have you looked into Maya? https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya

Comment: How is your data stored in the database? specially the date? Can you provide an example of what you are looking for? Like, user's input, expected returned value from dateutil, and how you use it to query the db?

Comment: @ThePoetCoder I had a look at the documentation and couldn't find anything that helps on my front. Can you please point me to the right function?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I had some basic ones, as I don't care what the format *is*, as I can write handling code around it. That said, I gave some examples above.

Comment: @robertlayton, did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yup. I was waiting to see if others would answer but I've accepted yours now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is some module to do that in python. I couldn't find any.

But internally dateutil parser first calls _parse to get the basic info like the date, month and year. It then calls _build_naive to fill the blanks with the datetime.datetime.now(). So we extend the parser class to write the function we require.

```
from dateutil.parser._parser import parser

class my_parser(parser):
    def __init__(self, info=None):
        super(my_parser, self).__init__(info)

    def specificity(self, timestr, default=None, ignoretz=False, tzinfos=None, **kwargs):
        # Do basic parsing, don't integrate current datetime
        res, skipped_tokens =  super(my_parser, self)._parse(timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
        if(res==None):
            print("dateutil parser couldn't parse the string")
            return None
        # Get the finest resolution 
        for attr in ("microsecond", "second", "minute", "hour", "day", "month", "year"):
            value = getattr(res, attr)
            if(value!=None):
                return attr
        print("Specificity couldn't be determined")
        return None

mp = my_parser()
print(mp.specificity("20/3/2018")) # day
print(mp.specificity("june")) # month
print(mp.specificity("2018")) # year
print(mp.specificity("12 june 12AM")) # hour
print(mp.specificity("12 june 12:00AM")) # minute
```